# What a "Comparable interface" specifically

Tags: java

Is "Comparable" a Single Abstract Method interface or an Abstarct interface in java ?(I am using it in a TreeSet and my class contains "compareTo" method)

Comment: It's an interface.

Comment: Comparable is a generic interface: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Comment: It's a functional interface, so, therefore, it has a single abstract method.  But then, functional interfaces can have static and default methods, so functional interface != single abstract method interface.

Comment: A `static` method is never abstract, and neither is a `default` method, so they don't affect how many abstract methods are in an interface, @NickZiebert.

Comment: @LewBloch Oh right, good point.

Answer (score 0):

> Java Comparable interface is used to order the objects of user-defined
>   class.This interface is found in java.lang package and contains only
>   one method named compareTo(Object). It provide single sorting sequence
>   only i.e. you can sort the elements on based on single data member
>   only. For example it may be rollno, name, age or anything else.

`public int compareTo(Object obj)`: is used to compare the current object with the specified object

Example is as below

```
class Student implements Comparable<Student>{  
int rollno;  
String name;  
int age;  
Student(int rollno,String name,int age){  
this.rollno=rollno;  
this.name=name;  
this.age=age;  
}  

public int compareTo(Student st){  
if(age==st.age)  
return 0;  
else if(age>st.age)  
return 1;  
else  
return -1;  
}  
}
```

And this compareTo method is used for sorting like below

```
public static void main(String args[]){  
ArrayList<Student> al=new ArrayList<Student>();  
al.add(new Student(101,"Vijay",23));  
al.add(new Student(106,"Ajay",27));  
al.add(new Student(105,"Jai",21));  

Collections.sort(al);  
for(Student st:al){  
System.out.println(st.rollno+" "+st.name+" "+st.age);  
}  
}
```

This will print the result like this

```
105 Jai 21
101 Vijay 23
106 Ajay 27
```

for more detail you can refer [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) link

Comment: Could you please be more specific Dhiraj ? Because I know what it does but what can you call it more specifically ?

Answer (score 0):

The term "abstract interface" in Java is not commonly used, @John Dafoe. All interfaces are abstract, regardless of whether they have zero, one, or more abstract methods.

If you look at the Javadocs for `Comparable`, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html, how many abstract methods do you see documented there? If there's only one, then it's a "Single-Abstract-Method" or "SAM" interface. If more than one, then it's a "more-than-one-abstract-method" interface.

Comment: So there is no such thing as an abstract interface but there is such thing as a single abstract method interface?  I'd say that the term "abstract interface" is redundant, not that there is no such thing.

Comment: I stand corrected. The JLS refers to the term "abstract interface".